# Joining data frame with dict data in one of it's columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My data looks like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'order_id': ['A', 'B'],
..                    'items': [[{'item': 1, 'color': 'blue' },
...                               {'item': 2, 'color': 'red'  }],
...                              [{'item': 3, 'color': 'green'},
...                               {'item': 2, 'color': 'pink' }]]},
...                   columns= ['order_id', 'items'])
>>> df
  order_id                                                          items
0        A    [{'item': 1, 'color': 'blue'}, {'item': 2, 'color': 'red'}]
1        B  [{'item': 3, 'color': 'green'}, {'item': 2, 'color': 'pink'}]
```

The column `items` contains dicts which I want to have as columns of the dataframe:

```
  order_id        item         color
0        A           1          blue
1        A           2           red
2        B           3         green
3        B           2          pink
```

i.e. every item of the dict should have an own row.

What I've done so far is to iterate row by row and create the data in a new dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['order_id', 'item', 'color'])
for row in df.iterrows():
    for items in (row[1]['items']):
        df2.loc[-1] =[row[1]['order_id'], items['item'], items['color'] ]
        df2.index += 1
```

which gives me the result I need:

```
>>> df2
  order_id item  color
3        A    1   blue
2        A    2    red
1        B    3  green
0        B    2   pink
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Maybe in place without creating another object and duplicating all the existing columns because I'm dealing with large amounts of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `repeat`, `join`, `len`

```
order_id = df.order_id.values.repeat(df['items'].str.len())
items = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df['items']).tolist())

items.assign(order_id=order_id)

   color  item order_id
0   blue     1        A
1    red     2        A
2  green     3        B
3   pink     2        B
```

---

#### Comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame([{**{'order_id': o}, **i} for o, I in df.values for i in I])

   color  item order_id
0   blue     1        A
1    red     2        A
2  green     3        B
3   pink     2        B
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC using `concat`

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df.set_index('order_id')['items']],keys=df.order_id).reset_index(level=0)
Out[486]: 
  order_id  color  item
0        A   blue     1
1        A    red     2
0        B  green     3
1        B   pink     2
```