# pandas.series.apply with self bultt function doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

I try to convert a series of strings to a series of mixed types, including strings and floats, with pandas.Series.apply function. However, it does't work. Can anyone give me a hint?

```
import pandas as pd 

series_a = ['a', '2', 'b', '3']

def value_to_float(value):
    try:
        value = float(value)
    except:
        pass
    return value

series_a.apply(value_to_float)

series[1]
Out[14]: '2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.to_numeric`

```
pd.Series([*'a2b3']).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')

0    a
1    2
2    b
3    3
dtype: object
```

Comment: I have learned a new piece of "syntactic sugar" `[*'a2b3']` instead of `list('a2b3')`.  Thanks. +1  Oh, and the code works as intended too. :-)

Comment: I've been sprinkling that sugar liberally. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52259398/2336654) is a good example of dictionary literal with unpacking.